# Restful API using Craft 3 with JWT

Tags: craft3

I want to make a Restful API with JWT in order to be able to make calls to it.

I have this in `/config/app.php`:

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        'my-module' => \modules\Module::class,
        'demarketsjwt' => \demarkets\Module::class,
    ],
    // 'bootstrap' => ['demarketsjwt'],
    'components' => [
        'listingsDb' => [
            'class' => craft\db\Connection::class,
            'driverName' => 'mysql',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . getenv('DB_LISTINGS_DBNAME') . ';port=' . getenv('DB_LISTINGS_DBPORT') . ';',
            'username' => getenv('DB_LISTINGS_USER'),
            'password' => getenv('DB_LISTINGS_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'enableSchemaCache' => !YII_DEBUG,
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'craft\web\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

and I have this in `/controllers/UserController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    // public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';ç
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $now = time();
        $rows = Craft::$app->listingsDb->createCommand("SELECT * FROM table;")->execute();
        echo $rows;
    }
}
```

I am doing tests with Postman app but I cannot make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Anyone please? I need help.

Comment: From a quick glance, you might need to disable CSRF routing on that controller.  You can disable per controller by setting a public property of  `$enableCsrfValidation` to false.

You can also disable it globally (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#enablecsrfprotection) but I would recommend only disabling it when necessary to maintain better security on your installation.

Comment: Ok I will do that and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonMcCallister I tried what you suggest but I keep getting `"error": "Template not found: users"` What do you suggest? Where should the controller be placed? how should the controller be named? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like its looking for the web, not API request. Try setting the Accept header on Postman to be application/json. I have this example module working as an API request: https://github.com/jasonmccallister/craft-console/blob/master/src/controllers/ApiController.php

Comment: I'm using the header `application/json` and I've seen your example but still getting `{
    "error": "Template not found: api/users"
}`